# Is there a webkit2 module for python?

Tags: python, webkit

I'm using python-webkit right now, but it's missing WebKitAuthenticationRequest, which I need. Is there a python webkit2 module, or maybe is there a way to do authentication in the old webkit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get WebKit2 from the `gi.repository` module (also known as **PyGObject**).

Make sure you have the following packages:

- python-gobject
- gir1.2-webkit2-3.0

You should then be able to use WebKit2 -

```
from gi.repository import WebKit2
```

*(Note that this module is for GTK+ 3).*

Comment: Looks as though the WebKit2 is for 17.10, but it's "WebKit" for the earlier versions... and the modules are not compatible.